# Firebase Cloud Functions wait for variables

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I wanna write img_thumb_url to firebase database. In func1A, my code i wrote below where I expect it can breakthrough the while loop when those global variable room and msg_key are not null but what I found it always undefined although those variables become defined with string value when func2B  successfully trigggered.

```
...
            while(1){
                if(room!=null && msg_key!=null){
                    console.log('room is ', room, '. msg_key is ', msg_key);
                    console.log('break from the loop');
                    break;
                }
            }
            admin.initializeApp();
             return admin.database().ref('/msgs/' + room + '/chat/' + msg_key + '/attachment/photo/thumbnail/url2').set(img_thumb_url);

             })
```

But the path above ' '/msgs/' + room + '/chat/' + msg_key + '/attachment/photo/thumbnail/url2 ' depends on variable room and msg_key retrieved from other function func2B which is here,

```
exports.func2B = functions.database.ref('/msgs/{roomName}/chat/{pushid}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        const msg = snapshot.val();
        if (msg.attachPhotoUrl == null) {
            console.log('No photo attachment found');
            return null;
        }
        if (msg_key != null) {
            console.log('msg_key no longer null');
            return null;
        }

       console.log('writing url2 for thumbnail in firebase database...');

        msg_key = msg.key;
        room = msg.roomName;
        console.log('room is ',room);
        console.log('msg_key is ',msg_key);
        console.log('img_thumb_url: ',img_thumb_url);
      return ....
    });
```

I'm not sure whether this is the proper way of method but I don't think it is as simple as that. Please help me how to resolve. How can i get that assigned value variable room and msg_key in func2B to func1A?

Comment: you cannot change variables outside of their scope; uses promises.

Comment: Jus to develop little understanding about 'promise'. Would you provide me a link to a sample code that looks similar to this case?